# Text to speech in Vista

Tags: delphi, windows-vista, text-to-speech

I did it by creating OLE object with Delphi in 2000/NT/XP as following:

```
Voice := CreateOLEObject('SAPI.SpVoice');
Voice.speak(...)
```

But this does not work in Vista, how can I make my program simply speak some text in Vista?

Comment: thanks François.
It works with the component in a the paper you suggested (http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2002/Speech/SAPI51/SAPI51.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried (D2009 on Vista Home Premium) with the following code and it works!

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComObj;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Voice: Variant;
begin
  Voice := CreateOLEObject('SAPI.SpVoice');
  Voice.speak('Hello World');
end;

end.
```

FYI, there is a [nice paper on using speech in Delphi programming](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2002/Speech/SAPI51/SAPI51.htm) by Brian Long...

---

**(Very) Late Update:**

For why it might not work in Vista and give an EZeroDivide exception outside the IDE, see this other SO question: [Delphi SAPI Text-To-Speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032739/delphi-sapi-text-to-speech)

Comment: Thanks for the paper. But, running the code you showed, in Vista, I get the error "Floating point division by zero". Did you test it in Vista? (I built it with BDS2006 in Windows XP and ran the executable in Vista)

Comment: I did build and test in Vista (on the same machine)

Comment: thanks François. It works with the component in a the paper you suggested (http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2002/Speech/SAPI51/SAPI51.htm)