# Vista Speech Recognition in Delphi

Tags: delphi, windows-vista, speech-recognition, text-services-framework

I would like to be able to dictate into my Delphi application using Microsoft Vista's speech recognition. However when attempting to dictate into a TMemo, it simply does not work. I noticed that Firefox 3.0 has the same issue and after they contacted Microsoft about the problem, they [told them](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=395484#c15) that they need to implement the [Text Services Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629032(VS.85).aspx) for their application.

I am wondering if there is any way to implement this in Delphi so that I can dictate into a TMemo or a TRichEdit. Searching Google for a solution didn't return any relevant results. Where would I start in finding a solution?

**Edit:** I found out that there is a way to enable speech recognition in all programs, even those that don't support it, simply by going to the options of Windows Speech Recognition and selecting **Enable dictation everywhere**. However when you use this to dictate into an editbox that doesn't use the Text Services Framework, it always pops up the **Alternates Panel** which displays the prompt **Say the number next to the item you want, followed by OK**. While this may work for short sentences, it does not have many of the useful features such as correcting or deleting a word. So I am still trying to figure out how to enable speech recognition without relying on the **Enable dictation everywhere** option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that there is a way to enable speech recognition in all programs, even those that don't support it, simply by going to the options of Windows Speech Recognition and selecting **Enable dictation everywhere**. However when you use this to dictate into an editbox that doesn't use the Text Services Framework, it always pops up the **Alternates Panel** which displays the prompt **Say the number next to the item you want, followed by OK**. While this may work for short sentences, it does not have many of the useful features such as correcting or deleting a word.

Comment: Even though this doesn't provide the best solution, I'm marking it as the best answer until someone can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score -2):

[Text to speech in Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207653/text-to-speech-in-vista)

Just tested it with a button like the demo code on that page, works fine in Vista SP1/D2007. (funny, I clicked the 'Vista' tag-link and found it there...)

Comment: The question is on Speech to text, not text to speech.